# Show image before click to upload file in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have code like this in my current angular project to upload a file:

```js
<input #file type="file" accept='image/*'  (change)="Loadpreview(file.files) " />
```

How can I change this so it can upload when the user clicks on an image instead?

Comment: Clicks on an image? Do you mean the image loaded by the user or another one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can you do it like this:

component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";
import { SafeUrl, DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  image: string | SafeUrl =
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521911528923-9c3838123490?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80";

  updateImage(ev) {
    this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(
      window.URL.createObjectURL(ev.target.files[0])
    );
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<p>
    Image uploader :)
</p>
<img [src]="image"  (click)="selectImage.click()">
<input type="file" (change)="updateImage($event)" style="display: none" #selectImage>
```

You essentially call the click handler by referencing the id of the input element

Please find a working example to your problem here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-62501330

Answer (score 0):

in the HTML:

```
<img src="image" alt=""  (click)="selectImage()">
```

in the ts:

```
selectImage()
{
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'file';
  input.accept="image/*";
  input.click();
}
```